# How do I access the callback from AutocompleteService.GetPredictions API call

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Using the Google Maps AutocompleteService, is there any way to get the callback function for the getpredictions call.

```
const options = {
  types: ['geocode'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},
  placeIdOnly: true
};
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autocompleteInput, options);
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
  this.locselected(auto_complete.getPlace());
});
```

Currently it fetches something like [this query](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?1sasgsdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg&4sen-US&7scountry%3Aus&9sgeocode&15e3&key=AIzaSyCnStpoOtW5nXYGHGxRFK0vHsruJhijKq8&callback=_xdc_._lpzdtk&token=129089) and automatically feeds it into the autocomplete component, which is what I would like to intercept.

Answer (score 2):

Create a promise and fetch the api inside promise argument function and response of that api call resolve function of this promise that way you can have callback for this api.

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of es6 promise you can set aside the headache of callback.Now you can use [XMLHttpRequest api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) along with [Promise api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to fetch the data and resolve it.

```
new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest()

    http.open('GET','your_autocoplet_api_url_here',true)

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){

            var result = http.response

            resolve(result) // when you resolve it it will go to the chainable 'then' method

        }
    }

    http.send()

}).then(result=>console.log(result)) // here you will receive the  resolved data, i mean the result from api call in result parameter of 'then' method
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you need is to use the [AutocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService) and call either `getPlacePredictions` or `getQueryPredictions` which lets you query the predictions API more precisely and takes a callback directly.

In this way you would have to manually put the results in the autocomplete component and maybe even build the component yourself, but it lets you get the prediction results before they're used for anything.